# Conditional comment in IE 9. Space between comment and conditional statement

Tags: internet-explorer-9, conditional-statements

I'm using the following IE conditional statement to load an IE-specific stylesheet. The statement works in IE 7, 8 and 9 Compatibility View. However, when I viewed the page in plain IE 9, the page was empty. I inspected it in developer tools, and it appears as though the conditional statement never closes, effectively commenting out the rest of the page.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link xmlns="" rel="stylesheet" href="http://colum.edu/Site_Files/localist/css/ie.css" /><[endif]-->
```

After a decent amount of hair-pulling, I finally figured out that if I add a space before the brackets for the conditional comment, it comment works in IE 9:

```
<!-- [if lt IE 9]><link xmlns="" rel="stylesheet" href="http://colum.edu/Site_Files/localist/css/ie.css" /><[endif]-->
```

The only difference is that there is a space between comment and the conditional statement...

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>   vs   <!-- [if lt IE 9]>
```

I can't figure out why on earth this is happening. Again, it only happens is "Browser Mode: IE9" not "Browser Mode: IE9 Compatibility view" with "Document Mode: IE9 standards". (I realize that the simplest solution is to add the space. However the real page lives on a hosted service, and I'm limited in what I can edit.) Anyways, here are some examples:

Not working: http://dev.ashramcreative.com/ccc/localist/ie9.html

Working: http://dev.ashramcreative.com/ccc/localist/ie9-space.html

Comment: Can anyone else even duplicate this?

Comment: Like Jeffrey said: “in your case it appears as though the <[endif]--> should be <![endif]-->”. Thus, your problem description is misleading. The reason why adding the space works is because then it becomes a normal comment. (And this also happens in IE8 and below.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was caused by a typo

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issues - how did you fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same thing; and adding the space before the conditional fixed IE9 in browser mode.

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953994/conditional-style-sheets-in-ie9) I was able to determine that a meta tag was to blame.

After I corrected the meta tag (in my case meta `http-equiv=content-type`), IE9 in browser mode worked correctly without the space.

However, in your case it appears as though the `<[endif]-->` should be `<![endif]-->`

Comment: Wow. I spent hours staring at the code, trying to figure out what was wrong. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Perhap, @dbhynds  you should edit your initial post, to signal that you posed an incorrect question.