# Conditional comment for meta tag doesnt work

Tags: internet-explorer, meta-tags, conditional-comments, x-ua-compatible

My site doesn't work well in IE9 but works ok in IE8 and IE10 so I decided to make it render in IE8 if the version is IE9 and if the version is higher than IE9, edge is ok for me.

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<![endif]-->
```

doesn't work, it always renders with edge. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a space after the opening comments as per this question: [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743385/conditional-comment-in-ie-9-space-between-comment-and-conditional-statement)

`<!--[if IE 9]>` vs. `<!-- [if IE 9]>`

Also note that IE10 doesn't support conditional comments [Microsoft support statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)